# Find the distance between two given points using lat-long in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have some 20 lat-long combination and I want to find distance of these 20 with 1000 other lat-long.
Does anybody have an Idea how can we do it using Excel.
Is it possible?
I can do it in Java but I just need the data so I want to do it in Excel...

Comment: If you can do it in Java, then why don't you apply the same formula in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use following formula.........

```
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-A2)) *COS(RADIANS(90-A3)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-A2)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-A3)) *COS(RADIANS(B2-B3))) *6371
```

Comment: Thnaks Nivesh its a great help

Answer (score 1):

You may find the extended reading on this site educational on this topic:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LatLong.aspx